# Getting the size of the callstack

Tags: c++, windows, callstack

Is there a way to get the size of the callstack (in bytes) in C++?
Or at least the bottom address of it (and then I can subtract it from the ESP register?

Comment: Just curious, why would you need to know it?

Comment: At the beginning of main, you can set a global pointer variable to the address of a local variable in the main() function.  Then you can subtract that global pointer address from a local variable to _estimate_ stack usage.

Comment: I've done it in the past to measure my maximum stack usage, and see if I needed to keep more object off, or was able to put more objects on it.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: You are making the assumption that stack frames are contiguous in memory. There is no requirement for this and some systems actually place stack frames in the heap to try and prevent stack smashing by malicious code.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum size that the callStack can grow to?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=vs.80).aspx shows that's settable (on windows) and defaults to 1MB.

Comment: @mooing Duck: no, just the current size of the stack.

Comment: @tux-d: really? are you talking about windows? or some other os? can you give some links or examples?

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  Do you mean the amount of stack space you are using, the amount of stack space remaining before the application will fail, or the total amount of stack space that can be used before the application will fail?

Comment: @ldov: I am talking in general. It is totally up to the compiler how it does it (there is no requirement in C++ that the stack is contiguous (or if there even is a stack)). The concept of the stack growing towards the heap is an abstract that makes it easy to teach students (and how it was done in the early days because it was easy). Their is not an actual need to implement it like this (though it can be) as such the information is not really useful.

Comment: A good place to start reading is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization Its a bit generic but it as a lot of references.

Comment: @Tux-D: so if the prceoss hides its stack, it's impossible to debug it or perform stackwalk on it, isn't it? because if you can find the EBP chain, you know where the frames are.

Comment: @Idov: OS detail. Check your OS documentation for details about how to find and navigate stack frames.

Comment: Note that the ia64 has *two* stacks. This may or may not be important, depending on what you need the stack size for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28VS.85%29.aspx) twice.

The first time you can use the address of any value on the stack to get the base address and size (in bytes) of the committed stack space.

Subtract the size from the base address and call VirtualQuery again. This way you get the space reserved for the stack.

Adding the two sizes you obtain the total stack size.

Comment: ok, and will this give me the *current* stack size? What do you mean "the base address"? the lowest address allocated for the stack?

Answer (score 2):

```
StackWalk64()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650

Comment: I'm not intersted in finding the number of frames in the callstack or in walking the callstack, but in its size in bytes.

Comment: Finding the number of stack frames is the **ONLY** way of measuring the size of the stack in a meaningful way.

Comment: By walking the stack-frame and adding up the differences between each frame-pointer in the call stack, you can get the total size of the stack.