# Stack Overflow occuring when moving my window (C++, winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

So I've got a sizable program, and a new error has started popping up that I can't seem to track down - and undoing the changes I remember doing recently hasn't proven fruitful. All the code below has been in there practically from the start of the program - still unchanged. I'm... confused, to say the least. ;_;

If it helps with diagnosis; I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and the OpenCV api.

So there are two ways that I can consistently get the error:

1. Attempt to grab the window by the Title Bar and *move* it.
2. Attempt to "hide" the options window after interacting with any of the options (even just clicking on a text box - no need to actually change/type anything).

   ```
   case WM_COMMAND:
       switch(LOWORD(wParam))
       {
           case IDOK:
               SendMessage(g_hOptions, WM_COMMAND, IDAPPLY, NULL);
               ShowWindow(g_hOptions, SW_HIDE); //Causes the issue
           break;
           case IDAPPLY:
               //Never Crashes Program
           break;
           case IDCANCEL:
               SendMessage(cboDotColors, CB_SETCURSEL, currentDot, 0);
               SendMessage(cboBackgroundColors, CB_SETCURSEL, currentBG, 0);
               SendMessage(cboCentralColors, CB_SETCURSEL, currentCen, 0);
               SendMessage(cboCornerColor, CB_SETCURSEL, currentCC, 0);
               SendMessage(cboSaveShots, CB_SETCURSEL, currentSS, 0);
               SendMessage(cboDebugMode, CB_SETCURSEL, currentDM, 0);
               SendMessage(cboTextOutput, CB_SETCURSEL, currentTO, 0);
               SendMessage(cboLighting, CB_SETCURSEL, lightingCondition, 0);
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_MINSIZE_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(minPixelCount).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_MAXSIZE_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(maxPixelCount).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_VISUALTHRESH_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(visualThreshold).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_ALIGNMENTTHRESH_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(alignmentThreshold).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_DELAY_MULTIPLIER_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(endDelayMultiplier).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_DELAY_DIVISOR_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(endDelayDivisor).c_str()));
               SetDlgItemText(g_hOptions, IDD_PICTURE_DELAY_ETB, const_cast<char *>(to_string(pictureWait).c_str()));
               ShowWindow(g_hOptions, SW_HIDE);
       {
   ```

(The above is somewhat truncated, since the other things don't seem to be interacting with / leading to the issue.)

Things that *don't* trigger it: Making the options window appear, moving the options window, making changes to the options window, applying those changes, moving focus away from/back to the program, using the program for it's normal functions, and letting it sit there doing nothing.

So here's the actual error that pops up from Visual Studio:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01447FB7 in ProjectNameHere.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x03332000).

The first and last numbers can vary.
If I hit "Continue" it goes to another error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01447FB7 in ProjectNameHere.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x03330000.

Same numbers vary here - and they remain consistent between the two errors.
That second error doesn't change further if I keep trying to push it - just repeating itself.

The thread running when it crashes is always: [10###] msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex
When I look at the "Call Stack" in VS, the most recent line executed that I actually wrote is "return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);"

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            g_hOptions = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_OPTIONS), hwnd, OptionsDlgProc);
            g_hbmBoard = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(targetBoardImg);
            g_hbmGreenLight = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(GreenLightOff);
            g_hbmWorkingLight = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(GreenLightOff);
            g_hbmWorkingIndicator = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(WorkingIndicatorNull);
            if(g_hbmBoard == NULL)
            {
                setExitError(1001);
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not load target board!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            }
            hDataBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY | WS_BORDER |
                ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
                screenResW - 349, 100, 315, 470,
                hwnd, (HMENU)NULL, NULL, NULL );
            CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Load and Process"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                screenResW - 349, 35, 315, 50,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_START_STOP, NULL, NULL );
            CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Clear Processing"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                screenResW - 349, 585, 155, 35,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON_CLEARPROCESSING, NULL, NULL );
            CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Save Data"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                screenResW - 349, 630, 155, 35,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_FILE_SAVE, NULL, NULL );
            CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Clear Data"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                screenResW - 189, 585, 155, 35,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_FILE_CLEAR, NULL, NULL );
            CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Quit"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                screenResW - 189, 630, 155, 35,
                hwnd, (HMENU) ID_FILE_EXIT, NULL, NULL );
        break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            g_hbmBoard = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(targetBoardImg);
            BITMAP bm;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

            HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hbmBoard);
            GetObject(g_hbmBoard, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hbmGreenLight);
            GetObject(g_hbmGreenLight, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            BitBlt(hdc, screenResW - 59, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hbmWorkingLight);
            GetObject(g_hbmWorkingLight, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            BitBlt(hdc, screenResW - 94, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, g_hbmWorkingIndicator);
            GetObject(g_hbmWorkingIndicator, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            BitBlt(hdc, screenResW - 129, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if(HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
            {
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    //case ID_BUTTON_CAMVIEW:
                        //{
                            //if(!camviewOn)
                            //{thread (displayCameraView).detach();}
                        //}
                    break; // Whoops! Not that this should affect anything...
                    case ID_FILE_SAVE:
                    {
                        if(textBoxCoords != "")
                        {
                            OPENFILENAME ofn;
                            WCHAR savefile[MAX_PATH+1] = L"";
                            ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
                            ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn); 
                            ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
                            ofn.lpstrFilter = (LPCSTR)"Text(*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files(*.*)\0*.*\0";
                            ofn.lpstrFile = (LPSTR)savefile;
                            ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
                            ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
                            ofn.lpstrDefExt = (LPCSTR)"txt";
                            if(textOutput){cout << "Choosing save file...\n";}
                            if(GetSaveFileName(&ofn))
                            {
                                ifstream checkFile;
                                checkFile.open(ofn.lpstrFile);
                                if(checkFile.good())
                                {
                                    checkFile.close();
                                    if(textOutput){cout << "File exists.\n";}
                                    if(MessageBox(hwnd, "File exists. Overwrite?", "Overwrite?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                                    {
                                        ofstream outputFile;
                                        outputFile.open ((ofn.lpstrFile), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
                                        if(outputFile.is_open())
                                        {
                                            outputFile << textBoxCoords;
                                            outputFile.close();
                                            if(textOutput){cout << "File overwritten.\n";}
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if(textOutput){cout << "File failed to open.\n";}
                                            MessageBox(hwnd, "File could not be saved.", "Error!",
                                                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                                            outputFile.close(); // Just in case.
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if(textOutput){cout << "File not overwritten.\n";}
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    checkFile.close();
                                    ofstream outputFile;
                                    outputFile.open ((ofn.lpstrFile), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
                                    if(outputFile.is_open())
                                    {
                                        outputFile << textBoxCoords;
                                        outputFile.close();
                                        if(textOutput){cout << "File Saved.\n";}
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if(textOutput){cout << "File failed to open.\n";}
                                        MessageBox(hwnd, "File could not be saved.", "Error!",
                                            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                                        outputFile.close(); // Just in case.
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {if(textOutput){cout << "File save canceled.\n";}}
                        }
                        else
                        {MessageBox(hwnd, "Nothing to save.", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);}
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_FILE_LOAD:
                    {
                        OPENFILENAME ofn;
                        WCHAR loadfile[MAX_PATH+1] = L"";
                        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
                        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn); 
                        ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
                        ofn.lpstrFilter = (LPCSTR)"Text(*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files(*.*)\0*.*\0";
                        ofn.lpstrFile = (LPSTR)loadfile;
                        ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
                        ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
                        ofn.lpstrDefExt = (LPCSTR)"txt";
                        if(textOutput){cout << "Choosing load file...\n";}
                        if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
                        {
                            ifstream inputFile;
                            inputFile.open(ofn.lpstrFile);
                            if (inputFile.is_open())
                            {
                                if(textBoxCoords == "" || MessageBox(hwnd, "Loading a file will clear all current datapoints. Unsaved data will be lost. Are you sure you want to proceed?",
                                    "Barrel full of monkeys?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                                {
                                    textBoxCoords = "";
                                    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
                                    textBoxCoords.reserve(inputFile.tellg());
                                    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
                                    textBoxCoords.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
                                    refreshTargetBoard();
                                    if(textOutput){cout << "Data loaded.\n";}
                                    inputFile.close();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(textOutput){cout << "File does not exist or cannot  be read.\n";}
                                    MessageBox(hwnd, "File could not be opened.", "Error!",
                                        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {if(textOutput){cout << "File load canceled.\n";}}
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_BUTTON_RESETERRORS:
                    {
                        exitCode = 0;
                        g_hbmGreenLight = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(GreenLightOff);
                        program_ON = false;
                        char Starp[6];
                        sprintf(Starp, "Start");
                        SetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, ID_START_STOP, (LPCSTR)Starp);
                        updateMainWindow();
                        clickPoint[0].X = -1; clickPoint[0].Y = -1;
                        clickPoint[1].X = -1; clickPoint[1].Y = -1;
                        clickPoint[2].X = -1; clickPoint[2].Y = -1;
                        clickPoint[3].X = -1; clickPoint[3].Y = -1;
                        done = true;
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_BUTTON_CLEARPROCESSING:
                    {
                        //Not written yet.
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_FILE_CLEAR:
                    {
                        if(textBoxCoords == "" || MessageBox(hwnd, "All unsaved data will be lost.\r\nAre you sure you wish to proceed?", "Make data go \"Bye-Bye\"?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                        {
                            textBoxCoords = "";
                            refreshTargetBoard();
                            if(textOutput){cout << "Data cleared.\n";}
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_FILE_OPTIONS:
                    {
                        if(g_hOptions != NULL)
                        {ShowWindow(g_hOptions, SW_SHOW);}//AnimateWindow(g_hOptions, 200, AW_ACTIVATE);}
                        else
                        {MessageBox(hwnd, "Options window failed to be created", "Warning!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);}
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_FILE_CALIBRATE:
                    {if(textOutput){cout << "Calibration window not yet available.\n";}}
                    break;
                    case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                    {exitProg = true; done = true; Sleep(30); PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);}
                    break;
                    case ID_HELP_INST:
                    {if(textOutput){cout << "Instructions window not yet available.\n";}} // TODO
                    break;
                    case ID_HELP_ABOUT:
                    {if(textOutput){cout << "About window not yet available.\n";}} // TODO
                    break;
                    case ID_LOAD_PROCESS:
                    {
                        if(exitCode == 0)
                        {
                            done = false;
                            if(!program_ON)
                            {
                                program_ON = true;
                                thread (pointProc).detach();
                                thread (workingIndicatorFunction).detach();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case ID_START_STOP:
                    {
                        if(exitCode == 0)
                        {
                            if(!program_ON)
                            {
                                g_hbmGreenLight = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(GreenLightOn);
                                program_ON = true;
                                char Starp[5];
                                sprintf(Starp, "Stop");
                                SetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, ID_START_STOP, (LPCSTR)Starp);
                                updateMainWindow();
                                done = false;
                                thread (pointProc).detach();
                                thread (workingIndicatorFunction).detach();
                                if(true) // Part of functionality that was changed earlier.
                                {
                                    const int MAX_SHOTFILE_LINES = 512;
                                    IplImage* imgB4;
                                    IplImage* imgAR;
                                    Mat TempB4;
                                    Mat TempAR;
                                    ifstream shotFile;
                                    shotFile.open("Input Pictures/ShotFile.txt");
                                    if(shotFile.good())
                                    {
                                        char shotFileLine[MAX_SHOTFILE_LINES][512] = {};
                                        int countUp = 0;
                                        string lineGot = "";
                                        while(!shotFile.eof() && countUp < MAX_SHOTFILE_LINES)
                                        {
                                            std::getline(shotFile, lineGot);
                                            int lineGotSize = lineGot.size();
                                            for(int i = 0; i < lineGotSize; i++)
                                            {shotFileLine[countUp][i] = lineGot.at(i);}
                                            countUp++;
                                        }
                                        for(int i = 0; i < countUp; i++)
                                        {
                                            if(isalnum(shotFileLine[i][0]))
                                            {
                                                string filenames[2];
                                                int fileCoords[8];

                                                int numSearch = 0;
                                                int numCheck = 0;
                                                int totalShotFileWords = 0;

                                                string shotFileLineStr(shotFileLine[i]);

                                                for(;numSearch < 512;numSearch++)
                                                {
                                                    if(shotFileLine[i][numSearch] == ' ' || shotFileLine[i][numSearch] == NULL)
                                                    {
                                                        if(totalShotFileWords < 2)
                                                        {
                                                            filenames[totalShotFileWords] = "Input Pictures/" + shotFileLineStr.substr(numCheck, (1+numSearch-numCheck));
                                                        }
                                                        else if(totalShotFileWords < 10)
                                                        {
                                                            for(int count = numCheck; count < numSearch; count++)
                                                            {if(!isdigit(shotFileLine[i][count])){goto malformed_coords;}}
                                                            istringstream(shotFileLineStr.substr(numCheck, (1+numSearch-numCheck))) >> fileCoords[totalShotFileWords-2];
                                                        }
                                                        numCheck = numSearch+1;
                                                        totalShotFileWords++;
                                                    }
                                                    if(shotFileLine[i][numSearch] == NULL){break;}
                                                }
                                                malformed_coords:
                                                if(totalShotFileWords < 2) // Not enough filenames
                                                {/*\Nothing Happens\*/}
                                                else if(totalShotFileWords < 10) // Not enough coords
                                                {
                                                    imgB4 = cvLoadImage( filenames[0].c_str(), 1);
                                                    if(imgB4 != NULL)
                                                    {
                                                        TempB4 = imgB4;
                                                        imgAR = cvLoadImage( filenames[1].c_str(), 1);
                                                        if (imgAR != NULL)
                                                        {
                                                            TempAR = imgAR;
                                                            Mat TestshotB4 = TempB4*1;
                                                            Mat TestshotAR = TempAR*1;
                                                            falsePics(TestshotB4, TestshotAR, ++audioCount);
                                                            cvReleaseImage(&imgB4);
                                                            cvReleaseImage(&imgAR);
                                                            delete imgB4;
                                                            delete imgAR;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else // Got everything
                                                {
                                                    imgB4 = cvLoadImage( filenames[0].c_str(), 1);
                                                    if(imgB4 != NULL)
                                                    {
                                                        TempB4 = imgB4;
                                                        imgAR = cvLoadImage( filenames[1].c_str(), 1);
                                                        if (imgAR != NULL)
                                                        {
                                                            TempAR = imgAR;
                                                            Mat TestshotB4 = TempB4*1;
                                                            Mat TestshotAR = TempAR*1;
                                                            coords testShotCyanCoordsA, testShotCyanCoordsB, testShotCyanCoordsC, testShotCyanCoordsD;
                                                            testShotCyanCoordsA.X = fileCoords[0]; testShotCyanCoordsA.Y = fileCoords[1];
                                                            testShotCyanCoordsB.X = fileCoords[2]; testShotCyanCoordsB.Y = fileCoords[3];
                                                            testShotCyanCoordsC.X = fileCoords[4]; testShotCyanCoordsC.Y = fileCoords[5];
                                                            testShotCyanCoordsD.X = fileCoords[6]; testShotCyanCoordsD.Y = fileCoords[7];
                                                            falsePics(TestshotB4, TestshotAR, ++audioCount, testShotCyanCoordsA, testShotCyanCoordsB, testShotCyanCoordsC, testShotCyanCoordsD);
                                                            cvReleaseImage(&imgB4);
                                                            cvReleaseImage(&imgAR);
                                                            delete imgB4;
                                                            delete imgAR;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    shotFile.close();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                g_hbmGreenLight = ConvertIplImageToHBITMAP(GreenLightOff);
                                program_ON = false;
                                char Starp[20];
                                sprintf(Starp, "Load and Process");
                                SetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, ID_START_STOP, (LPCSTR)Starp);
                                updateMainWindow();
                                done = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
                    break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if(textBoxCoords == "" || MessageBox(hwnd, "Are you certain you wish to exit?\r\nAll unsaved data will be lost.", "Leaving so soon?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
        }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            if(textOutput){cout << "\nExiting.\n\n";}
            else{if(IsWindow(consoleWindow)){ShowWindow(consoleWindow, SW_SHOW);} cout << "\nExiting.\n\n";}
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        break;
        default:
            cout << setw(10) << hwnd << setw(10) << msg << setw(15) << wParam << setw(15) << lParam << endl;
            //Recent addition when this started. If you think the info I get from this would help, please ask!
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); // <===This thing!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The actual code that it crashes on is in "chkstk.asm": "test    dword ptr [eax],eax"

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
        sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
        test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page. <====
        jmp     short cs10
```

Here is the full Stack Trace/Call Stack from Visual Studio:

```
Project1.exe!_chkstk() Line 99  Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
msctf.dll!UIComposition::UpdateCompositionRect(class IMCLock &) Unknown
msctf.dll!CIMEUIWindowHandler::ImeUINotifyHandler(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)   Unknown
msctf.dll!CIMEUIWindowHandler::ImeUIWndProcWorker(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)   Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageToUI@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeNotifyHandler@16()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcWorker@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcW@16()    Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcWorker@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
user32.dll!_DefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
Project1.exe!WndProc(HWND__ * hwnd=0x000f04be, unsigned int msg=642, unsigned int wParam=11, long lParam=0) Line 1842   C++
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
imm32.dll!_MakeIMENotify@28()   Unknown
imm32.dll!_ImmSetCompositionWindow@8()  Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeSetContextHandler@16()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcWorker@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcW@16()    Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcWorker@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
user32.dll!_DefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
Project1.exe!WndProc(HWND__ * hwnd=0x000f04be, unsigned int msg=641, unsigned int wParam=1, long lParam=-1073741809) Line 1842  C++
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
imm32.dll!_ImmSetActiveContext@12() Unknown
user32.dll!_FocusSetIMCContext@8()  Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeSystemHandler@16()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcWorker@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!_ImeWndProcW@16()    Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
user32.dll!_GetWindowInfo@8()   Unknown
user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
user32.dll!_DefWindowProcA@16() Unknown
Project1.exe!WndProc(HWND__ * hwnd=0x000f04be, unsigned int msg=6, unsigned int wParam=1, long lParam=1640404) Line 1842    C++
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
user32.dll!_GetWindowInfo@8()   Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallDlgProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcWorker@20()   Unknown
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcA@16()    Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@20()  Unknown
user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
user32.dll!_xxxButtonNotifyParent@8()   Unknown
user32.dll!_xxxBNReleaseCapture@8() Unknown
user32.dll!_ButtonWndProcWorker@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_ButtonWndProcA@16() Unknown
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()   Unknown
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageA@4()    Unknown
Project1.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00000000, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance=0x00000000, char * lpCmdLine=0x00000000, int nCmdShow=1) Line 1914 C++
Project1.exe!std::_Bind<0,void,int (__stdcall*)(HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int),HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::operator()() Line 1152   C++
Project1.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,int (__stdcall*)(HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int),HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> >::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,int(__stdcall*)(HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int),HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> > * _Ln=0x0012fafc) Line 196  C++
Project1.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<0,void,int (__stdcall*)(HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int),HINSTANCE__ *,HINSTANCE__ *,char *,int,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> >::_Go() Line 187 C++
msvcp110d.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data=0x0012fafc) Line 52   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 354 C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd=0x00bcaba8) Line 337    C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

I'm not actually certain where to go from here. Help?

(If you need more information about it, please ask - I'm not entirely certain what's relevant here, and there's a lot of code and a lot of data... EDIT: This should now be apparent to all...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667440/monitoring-call-stack-size-in-visual-studio/11667832#11667832

Comment: @HansPassant I saw that one - it did not help my issue. Somehow the breakpoint is skipped and I end up going straight to the error.

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added Visual Studio's Call Stack if that helps.

Comment: That stack is not very deep. The fact that there is a chkstk call in your wndproc tells me that you have really huge local variables that are eating up your stack. There should never be a chkstk in your window procedure.

Comment: @RaymondChen Wouldn't that mean that increasing the stack size would solve the issue? During its normal course of operation, the program will create many more (and much larger) variables that it needs to sort through than what is used at the start - and it can go through that whole thing without issue. So then why would this occur when simply clicking&dragging the title bar? - and that's without having even started up its main functions... (Just clicking on it doesn't trigger the crash - not that that would make any more sense to me...).

Comment: Clicking and dragging the title bar enters a modal loop, which deepens the stack. You really need to take the big variables out of your wndproc's stack. I bet you don't need those stack variables when handling a `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message, for example.

Comment: @RaymondChen I only had 2 ints declared outside the switch statement in LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc() - I'm assuming that's what you meant. I removed them but the error is still occurring. Unless there is another WndProc that I didn't write that I need to track down...

Comment: What about the variables *inside* the switch statement? They all take up space in the stack frame. You should take each `case` and make it a separate function.

Comment: @RaymondChen Well... that... uh... I'm confused. That _worked_; but I never had any variables declared inside the switch statements because I always got an error when doing that - is just *using* them in there (via globals) that bad? - Anyway, I moved all but WM_CLOSE and WM_DESTROY out into their own functions and it's working, so thank you so much for the help! If you want to put it as an answer I will happily upvote and accept it.

Comment: Show us all the actual WndProc code and someone will tell you exactly which variables are causing the issue - without that we can only really guess.

Comment: @MikeVine It might be a large compiler-generated temporary.

Comment: Go ahead and post your own answer (since it involves information that only you know - like the code that you just called "Do stuff" in your post). If you edit the code before posting, make sure the edited code still has the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @MikeVine I know it's a bit late (things get busy in December >.<) but I made the edit to throw in all the code in WndProc. If you'd be so kind as to take a look. At this point: I have the solution but I don't understand it. Your insight would still be appreciated.

Comment: @ Alexander Just taking a glance through your code you've got a lot of things allocated on the stack, but 'char shotFileLine[MAX_SHOTFILE_LINES][512] = {}' is big which is then exacerbated by WindProc being on the stack three times. Either dynamically allocate this (std:vector<byte>?), reduce its size or refactor out the ID_START_STOP case into its own function and it _probably_ will fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Look deeper into the call stack. One common reason for stack overflows is infinite recursion. Does `DefWindowProc` somehow do something which ends up calling  `WndProc`, which then calls `DefWindowProc`, which then calls `WndProc`? There may be several layers of function calls in between.

It could also simply be an excessive use of the stack. One of several ways to increase stack size is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx

Other possible reasons are massive allocations on the stack (often involving `alloca`), or stack corruption.

Comment: DefWindowProc is getting called multiple times; but just about everything I do (successful or otherwise) results in it being called multiple time. For example; when crashing via closing the options window, it gets called 19 times. When I close it successfully it calls it the same 19 times with the same msg parameter (slightly different wParams and lParams  for some of them) plus an additional 3 times. The crashing variant calls DefWindowProc(00120888, 642, 11, 0) while the successful equivalent calls DefWindowProc(00120888, 642, 2, 0) - I never defined DefWindowProc and can't seem to find it.

Comment: Between this (DefWindowProc only being called 19 times by the action that kills it) combined with my response to HansPassant in the above comments; I am unconvinced that this is being caused by infinite recursion - or at least infinite recursion in my code. I don't know if something new is happening in the Windows API.

Comment: Look at the message numbers.

Comment: @Peter I'm... not actually certain how to check that, but they shouldn't be. WndProc is defined in my program, and calls DefWindowProc, but not itself. DefWindowProc is defined in the Windows API so I'm not sure how to see what it's calling - although I have to at least somewhat doubt it's calling itself or my WndProc. It's just meant for going through the checklist of things WndProc didn't handle as I understand it. Is that wrong?

Comment: I tried your edit and increased to 4mb - exact same result - same number of calls before dying.

Comment: The good news is that the problem isn't infinite recursion (of WndProc), otherwise you'd get more calls with a larger stack (unless there's an error when counting the number of calls). The bad news is you still have something that either creates an infinite recursion (of a function other than WndProc), allocates a massive data structure (>3mb) on the stack, or corrupts the stack :( Sorry that I can't be more helpful than this.

Comment: @Peter - No worries, and Thanks. I gave you an upvote for helping me eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: I second looking at the message numbers. What kind of program are you writing?

Comment: Remember, the call that overflows the stack is not the interesting one. You want the calls in the repeating section.

Comment: @RaymondChen - Assuming there is a repeating section. The stack isn't filling up in a short increment - the program crashes before it realizes a quarter of the stack space is used. This means that something is using >75% of the stack space in a single go or we're we're looking at something else and the error is being reported incorrectly be VS. Or something else entirely, I suppose.

Comment: @andlabs - Which message numbers are you referring to?

Comment: The ones Raymond was telling you about, the second argument to your WndProc and DefWindowProc ([which you should have had from the beginning by the way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/05/55936.aspx)) calls. In the example you listed earlier when talking to Peter, you said you kept getting 642, which is WM_IME_NOTIFY (if you don't know what that is, you're probably not using it). Monitoring which messages come in and out of your window procedures is critical in debugging these things.

Comment: @andlabs I'm getting a lot of different numbers that I'm not using myself. 20, 312, 309, 70, 134, 147, 145, 146, 6, 641, & 642 are what come up shortly before it crashes when closing the options window. When I try to grab and move it by the title bar I get 132, 32 (mouse movement?), 161, 274, 533, 36, 561, 534, 674, & 70. I have been monitoring them - I just can't find a list of their meanings. Also - 642 is sent even when I close the options window without crashing it - shortly followed by 7, & 312.